# How to read a file which is currently used, like Windows does when copying it?

Tags: c#, ioexception, file-access

One of my applications is intended to read (and only read) files which may be in use.

But, when reading a file which is already opened in, for example, Microsoft Word, this application throws a `System.IO.IOException`:

> The process cannot access the file '<filename here>' because it is being used by another process.

The code used to read the file is:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete))
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Of course, since the file is already used, this exception is expected.

Now, if I ask the operating system to copy the file to a new location, then to read it, it works:

```
string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.Copy(fileName, tempFileName, true);
//                                         ↓ We read the newly created file.
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete))
{
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

What is the magic of `File.Copy` which allows to read the file already used by an application, and especially how to use this magic to read the file without making a temporary copy?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Is it possible you're specifying FileAccess.Write in your app, even though it's not in your snippet above?

Comment: As Ciaran Keating says above your original code works for me.  What are you doing in the "// Do stuff here."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question there. Have a look at this, it seems to suggest using FileShare.ReadWrite only is the key, it's worth a shot.

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/viewD21B312F-242A-4038-9E9B-AE6AAB53DAE0.htm

Comment: Reading the comments, it seems that it works in some circumstances, and doesn't in others. In my case, with a file already opened by Microsoft Word, switching to `FileShare.ReadWrite` does not solve the problem.

Comment: That's annoying, this blogpost also suggests the same thing. http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2005/03/how-to-read-file-thats-in-use-by.html It does appear to be a problem with it *already* being read, as opposed to subsequent reads (your app).

Comment: As a further sidenote, using File.Open returns a FileStream, as suggested here: http://aautar.digital-radiation.com/blog/?p=1292

Answer (score 0):

try removing `FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete` from the FileStream constructor, or at least FileShare.Delete.

Comment: these flags specify what *other* file streams are allowed to have, not the one that is being opened at the time - as such specifying these flags makes the lock required a *weaker* one, so your statement is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but your sharing mode must be consistent with those of other existing handles to the file. Just what's "consistent" is a little unclear to me. For example, while Word has a file open I can open it with a sharing mode of Read|Write, but not just Read on its own or Write on its own.